# What is the approximation obtained with the midpoint method after one step, answer is a function of h?

Tags: numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, runge-kutta-methods

Write down the approximation obtained with the midpoint Runge Kutta method after one step
(the answer will be a function of h).

I am stuck on this part for a first-order system. I'm not sure how to implement my system into the midpoint RK method

The RK midpoint method is
$$ K_1 = f(t_n,y_n) \\ K_2 =f(t_n + \frac{h}{2},y_n +\frac{h}{2}K_1) \\y_{n+1} = y_n + hK_2
$$

The original IVP is
$$ y'' + 2y' + y = te^{-t} - 1    \\y(0) = y'(0) = 0 \\0\leq t \leq1
$$

My system is
$$ y_1' = y_2
$$

$$ y_2' = te^{-t} -1 -2y_2 -y_1
$$
where $y_1(0) = y_2(0) = 0$

Comment: You switch from $h$ in the title to $\Delta t$ in the body.  Plug your system into your Runge-Kutta equations.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: im not sure how to implement my system into the midpoint rk method

Comment: I can't help unless you write out the equations for the method.

Comment: i added it now.

Answer (score 1):

When you have two equations, $f$ and the $K$s are two position vectors.  Now $y=\begin{pmatrix} y_1\\y_2 \end {pmatrix}$.  You should write your system as a single equation working on two position vectors.  The second argument of $f$ is also a two position vector.  You are given $y_0$ and $t_0$.  Plug them in to get $K_1$.  Plug them and $K_1$ in to get $K_2$

Added:  You may have confusion about the subscripts.  The subscripts $1,2$ are the variables, the subscripts $n$ are the values of the variables at time step $n$.  So at $t=0, y_{10}=y_{20}=0.$  You plug those into $K_{10}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\-1 \end {pmatrix}$  Then $K_{20}=f\left(\frac h2,\frac h2\begin{pmatrix} 0\\-1 \end {pmatrix}\right)$ and you plug those last into the right side of your equations to compute $K_{20}$

Comment: could you possibly do y_1, im still lost sorry.